# Увеличить ключ массива на 1

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
 $arr = array(
    0 => 'one',
    1 => 'two',
    2 => 'three'
 );
```

Нужно, чтобы было

```
 $arr = array(
    1 => 'one',
    2 => 'two',
    3 => 'three'
 );
```

Кто-нибудь знает как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Если структура индексов всегда именно такая, можно просто построить новые и объединить со значениями

```
array_combine(range(1, count($arr)), $arr);
```

Comment: здорово. начиная с индекса 1, длинной в наш массив и заполнить им же)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $arr = array(
    0 => 'one',
    1 => 'two',
    2 => 'three'
 );

$temp = [];
 foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $temp[$key+1] = $value;
 }

 var_dump($temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count($arr);
for($i=$count; $i>0; $i--) {
    if (isset($arr[$i-1])) {
        $arr[$i] = $arr[$i-1];
    }
}
unset($arr[0]);
```

Код не тестировал, возможно где то ошибка.