# Как в preg_split'е разбить элементы по ключам начиная с 1. А не с 0 как по умолчанию

Tags: php

```
preg_match('~\[img_list\](.*?)\[/img_list\]~s', $text, $search); // Ищем находим и берем
$text = preg_replace('~\[img_list\](.*?)\[/img_list\]~s', '', $text); // Убираем найденное
$img_list = preg_split('~\n~', $search[1]); // найденное разбиваем на массив, к примеру 3 элемента.
```

Дело в том, что дальше с этими элементами я буду работать. Но элементы должны быть нумероваться с 1 по так далее.

Comment: Либо после сплита переназначить. Но голова не варит(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437535/186083

Comment: А я кипел ужс :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить в regex начало строки как одну из альтернатив и потом удалить пустой нулевой элемент из результата

```
$arr = preg_split('/^|\d/', 'a2b3c'); // [0=> '', 1=>'a', 2=>'b'...]
unset($arr[0]);                       // [1=>'a', 2=>'b'...]
```